# Rails/Ajax not replacing DIV instead nesting new DIV inside old DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying to update a DIV with ajax, after a form is submitted.

My partial _inline.html.erb is

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-10 columns left"><%= post.content %></div>
    <div class="large-2 columns right"><%= link_to 'Remove', post, method: :delete,  class: 'tiny button' %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My js.erb is

```
$('#inline_posts').html("<%= j render 'posts/inline' %>");
$('#new_post').html("<%= j render 'posts/form' %>");
```

The re-rendering of the form is fine.  The form is redrawn as if new.

The rendering of the DIV is the issue. It renders the new DIV instead of the old DIV.  Why does it not replace the existing DIV just as with the form it replaces the existing form?

The DIV once updated via AJAX looks like

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">
  <div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">
```

putting a new version of it, inside the old version.

Edit:

Form HTML

```
<div class="large-12 columns"> <--- Note this has no id specified
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" data-remote="true" id="new_post" method="post">
<div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label for="post_Post a message">Post a message</label>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 columns">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="post_content" name="post[content]">
</textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="large-2 columns">
    <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Post" />
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

The forms partial  posts/_form.html.erb (this creates a form with the id "new_post")

```
<%= form_for(@post, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <%= f.label 'Post a message' %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 columns">
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="large-2 columns">
    <%= f.submit  'Post', class: 'button' %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I didnt include it because there is no issue with it. it outputs fine exactly as expected.  I can put if if its pertinent, but the problem occurs even if i remove that portion of the javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.html` is just a graceful wrapper for `.innerhtml` so whatever is rendered by `posts/inline` will be placed inside the `inline_posts` div tag

You might want to try [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('#inline_posts').replaceWith("<%= j render 'posts/inline' %>");
```

if you want that element `#inline_posts` to be replaced with whatever is rendered by `posts/inline`

EDIT:

When you call, `$('#inline_posts').html("<%= j render 'posts/inline' %>");`

You are basically taking the html that is inside `posts/inline` template file and placing it within the `inline_posts` div, like so:

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">INSERTING posts/inline HTML HERE</div>
```

Your `posts/inline` template file *must be* starting with `<div class="large-12 columns" id="inline_posts">` otherwise you wouldn't get the results you are getting.

It works for your form because your `posts/form` template file doesn't begin with `<form id="new_posts">`  thus, the html in your posts file is rendering inside that element, like so:

```
<form id="new_posts">INSERTING posts/form HTML HERE</form>
```

`form#new_posts` is not part of your template file, where as `div#inline_posts` must be part of its respective template file.  That's why you are nesting with one but not the other.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks.  Why does it work for the form? The form is replaced fully not nested within itself.

Comment: Whatever is being rendered in `posts/form` is being nested within `<div id="new_post"></div>` element.  I would need to see the template for `posts/form` to give you a more complete answer.

Comment: I updated my post to add the form's HTML. the form's id is "new_post" not the surrounding DIV

Comment: I edited my answer, hopefully the behavior you are seeing makes more sense :)

Comment: I'm confused, there is no DIV#New_Posts, if there were i'd understand what you said. NEW_POSTS is the Form's own ID.

Comment: I'll edit my answer so that instead of `<div id="new_posts"></div>`  I'll put `<form id="new_posts"></form>`. But, as far as html elements go, there is no difference.

Comment: with your new answer, "INSERTING posts/form HTML HERE"  why is the form tag not inserted again, its in the partial.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Because you can't have form within a form,  Rails/browser/something may be filtering out the extra form tag.  I'll have to test it later.  Sorry for the confusion. But the over arcing point still stands, `.html()` only replaces the code inside the tag of the selected element.